# Representations of $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\bar{\mathbb{C}}$ with winding number $k\neq0$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-space-isomorphism, winding-number

In the text I'm reading, $U(1)$ has a representation on $\mathbb{C}$ with winding number $k$ given by:
$$z\mapsto z^k$$
I'm supposed to show that the representations of $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ with winding number $k$ on $V_k\cong\mathbb{C}$ and $\bar{V}_k$ are not isomorphic. I started by defining my representation of $U(1)$ on $V_k$ as:
$$\Phi_{V^k}:e^{i\theta}\rightarrow e^{ik\theta}$$
I then said that the induced represenation of $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ on $V_k$ would be :
$$\Phi_{V^k*}:X\rightarrow ikX$$
where $X\in \mathbb{R}$ since the Lie algebra of $U(1)$ is just $i\mathbb{R}$. So now I just need to show that a $g$ equivariant isomorphism from $V_k$ to $\bar{V}_k$ does not exist, but if I define the isomorphism $F:V_k\rightarrow \bar{V}_k$ such that:
$$F(a)=\bar{a}$$
how is this not $g$ equivariant? Wouldn't $(ikX)\cdot (a)$ just get mapped to $-ikX \bar{a}$ which would be $\Phi_{\bar{V}^k*}(X)F(a)$? I'm failing to see what I'm missing.

Comment: An equivariant isomorphism of complex linear representations should certainly be an isomorphism of complex vector spaces. Is that the case here?

Comment: @kajelad I want to say no, but I don’t know why, especially since I recently “showed” $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ has isomorphic representations on $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\bar{\mathbb{C}}^2$ And I can’t see what the difference is.

Comment: @Kajelad I voted to close this question, as I do not think it is suitably explaining where my confusion lies. I posted a new question [here]:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398239/confusion-regarding-isomorphisms-of-representations, and would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look.

Comment: I believe @Kajelad is pointing to the simpler fact that conjugation is not complex linear and so not an isomorphism of complex vector spaces.

Comment: @Callum, I don’t see how Any representation could be considered isomorphic to its conjugate representation then. Yet, I’m supposed to show in the other question I asked that $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ has a fundamental rep that is isomorphic to the conjugate rep. Further, while not canonically isomorphic, since they have the same dimension should they not be isomorphic to one another as complex vector spaces?

Comment: As I commented under your other question, I think you have an (understandable) misconception about what the conjugate representation actually is.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I responded to your comment over on the other question.  What is the conjugate representation, explicitly, though?